# How do you pass model data to a template using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to pass data from a Django model into an HTML template using a class based view.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('review/', views.ReviewRecord.as_view(template_name='review.html'), name='review')
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.model):
    RegNumber = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    Description = models.TextField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
from app.models import MyModel
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ReviewRecord(TemplateView)
    template_name = 'review.html'
    model = myModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['description'] = self.model.description
        return context
```

html

```
<textarea readonly>{{ description }}</textarea>
```

The above code inserts the following into the html textarea:

```
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000024C449B9F88>
```

I need to display the stored field data from the model, not the object data as stated above.

I am trying to create a queryset based on a field in the model, for example, for a particular RegNumber.  Eventually I would like to retrieve several records and be able to increment through them, however I am currently just trying to get one to work. I have also tried using a DetailView using the primary key in the url, however I keep getting errors, therefore the provided example code is from what appears to be my closest attempt to my goal.

Comment: `self.model` is the model class, you need an instance thereof.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass **model instances/queryset** instead of the **model class** as mentioned in the comments

```
class ReviewRecord(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'review.html'
    model = Mymodel
    pk = 1

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # specfic instance description
        context['Description'] = Mymodel.objects.get(pk=self.pk).Description
        # all instances' descriptions
        context['all_descriptions'] = Mymodel.objects.values_list('Description', flat=True)
        # pass other variables
        context['other_var'] = 'other_var'
        return context
```

Comment: Your solution returns "MyModel matching query does not exist", despite confirming that a record with the corresponding RegNumber/pk value exists.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way to do what you need is this.

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MyModel

def review_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    # Getting all the stuff from database
    query_results = MyModel.objects.all();

    # Creating a dictionary to pass as an argument
    context = { 'query_results' : query_results }

    # Returning the rendered html
    return render(request, "review.html", context)
```

models.py : Here, make sure you write models.Model instead of models.model

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    RegNumber = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    Description = models.TextField(null=True)
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from app.views import review_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('review/', review_view , name='review')
]
```

The file review.html. Make sure you specify the correct DIR for templates in the settings.py to avoid template not found error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

        {% for item in query_results %}
           <h1>{{ item.RegNumber }}</h1>
           <p>{{ item.Description }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: while function based views are easier to understand (imo) the question is about a class based view. Maybe you find the solution to the original problem. The person asking the question might try to avoid function based views for some reason...

Comment: I am attempting to use class based views as I believe it makes more sense for the particular application I am working on.  That said, I am open to anything that will achieve my goal of being able to retrieve data from my database and pass it to my template.  I attempted to implement this solution and did not receive an error, however what was passed to my template was "<QuerySet []>".